# DataGen in soapui or soapui pro?

Tags: rest, testing, soapui, data-generation

I want to test Restful web service in SoapUI. For that, I need to read values from Excel and pass that to request.

I searched in net, I found that it is possible through [DataGen TestStep](https://www.soapui.org/docs/data-driven-tests/datagen-teststep.html). I have SoapUI, but I couldn't find that option.

Can someone please tell if DataGen TestStep is available in SoapUI-4.5.1 or SoapUI Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure that the data sources and such are only in SoapUI pro.  You can accomplish the same thing in groovy scripts, though, but you would probably be better off reading from a text file as opposed to a spreadsheet.

Comment: SOAPUI has no support for Datageneration or Datasourcing methods. You can go with SOAPUI Pro version

Answer (score 1):

The step is available only in Soap UI Pro only(Ready API)

In free version that is Soap UI, you can use POI way of reading an excel file via groovy scripting and pass those values in your input request.

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;

def fs = new FileInputStream("F:\\Gaurav\\soapui\\readFile.xlsx")
def wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs)
def ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1")
def r = ws.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()

for(def i =0 ; i < r ; i++)
{
def row = ws.getRow(i);
def c=row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells()

for(def j=0; j <c ; j++)
{
def cell= row.getCell(j)

// to convert everything to a String format
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter()
def cellValue=formatter.formatCellValue(cell)

log.info cellValue

}
}
```

// Above is the code to read from excel. Once you have read the values, you can // store the values in property

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue(tcprop,"cellValue")
```

then in your request you can expand it like below

```
${#TestCase#tcprop}
```

This way you can achieve the same DataGen thing in Soap UI free version 4.5

Answer (score 0):

So, there is an option in SoapUI Setup Script that could be run in advance 
You can convert your Excel to csv or text file and handle the date from there.

I've done some testing with REST services, used only reading from the text file feature.
the code like this:

```
//Load the text file
 def inputFile = new File("C://Temp//whatever");

//Create an empty list...
 def mega_List = [];

//...and then populate it with the contents
 // of the text file.
 addSomeThingToList = {mega_List.add(it)};
 inputFile.eachLine(addSomeThingToList);

//...and assign its value to the Test Case Property
 def tc = testRunner.testCase;


//Randomly pick an item from the list...
def index = context.expand( '${#TestCase#index}' ).toInteger()


 if ( index <  mega_List.size() ) { 
def id = mega_List.get(index);
 index++
tc.setPropertyValue("id", id);
tc.setPropertyValue("index", index.toString());

 }
else {
tc.setPropertyValue("index", "0");
tc.setPropertyValue("id", "0");
testrunner.cancel( "time to go home" )
}
```